# framing nailers : low profile for blocking but also with interchangeable tips for framing and use with metal connectors

Tags: powertools, framing-fasteners

Is there such a tool as a low-profile framing nailer that can fit between studs set  16" o.c. for nailing blocking, but which also has swappable tips so it can do frame nailing of 2x members as well as aim nails accurately into the holes of metal-connectors?  I've found the one, or the other, but not both.

Comment: The OP's not asking for a recommendation, just if the tool exists.

Comment: Agreed, @JACK, but we seem to close all of these "does a tool exist that does `x`" type questions. I think it's because the answer is either "yes" or "no" (which kinda makes the Q off topic), or it's a shopping recommendation as K H as done... It's unfortunate, because sometimes people (me included!) just don't know if a thing exists and if so, what it's called... This one does have a good answer, though, so the knee-jerk reaction isn't always called for.

Comment: @FreeMan: Not sure why that it can be answered Yes or No makes a question off-topic. I won't waste my time searching for such a tool if someone who is familiar with the subject tells me that the two tasks I mentioned are handled by separate tools. I've found nailers that can hold 60 nails that are designed to fit between studs for blocking, and nailers that can hold 60 nails that have a swappable tip for use with metal connectors, both by the same company, but the more compact tool does not have the swappable tip option.

Comment: I don't know why, either, but that seems to be the way it is 'round here. A simple "yes"/"no" answer will get flagged as being too short, and likely deleted. I'm _not_ arguing that it's _right_, just that it _is_.

Comment: @FreeMan  As usual, you bring up a good point and indeed could go either way.  I've answered a few with a "yes"  and maybe a picture but then put in a disclaimer about not recommending it or owning the company.  I too have done jobs and have thought, or said, "there's got to be an easier way, a tool that will do this".   But we didn't have this site so we kept on doing it the hard way.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will either find framing nailers or palm nailers, but not some combination , from the major brands at least. A good ol' hammer will do both but not offer the productivity or efficiency you seek.

Comment: +100 on the pneumatic palm nailer! I used one (two, actually on an air hose splitter) to drive all the joist hanger nails on my deck about 2 years ago. Noisy little buggers but they work a treat! Hearing protection is recommended. Then, you get whatever type of framing nailer your heart and/or needs require.

Comment: I do have one of the pneumatic palm nailers. Mine takes about 10 seconds per 16d nail. For the number of nails I have to drive on this next DIY project, that would be far from ideal.

Comment: I, too, used them on 16d nails, @mrblint. Mine were 1.5" joist hanger nails, though, not 3" framers, so that might make a difference.

Comment: I also had a neighbor who lives six houses away come down to see what all the racket was about. Those palm nailers are like miniature jackhammers.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to consider getting a [pea shooter slide hammer](http://www.bigfootsaws.com/bigfootproduct/pea-shooter-slide-hammer/) or just making one from 1/2" pipe and rebar/rod.  Usually you need a second person to position while you operate the slide hammer, but it will get a nail into extremely awkward places.  It can't nail perpendicular due to the long shaft of course.